# Django | Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a create endpoint in restframework that works fine.
**views** is as follows

```
class ItemAddAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser]

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            item_obj = Item.objects.create(title=serializer.data['title'],
                            discount=serializer.data['discount'],
                            rate_per_kg=serializer.data['rate_per_kg'])
            return Response(serializer.data, status=HTTP_201_CREATED)
        except Exception as e:
            print("error :: ",e)
```

**serializer** is given below:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields='__all__'
```

This works fine. But when I add a SerializerMethodField() to the Serializer it gives the error :

> Field 'id' expected a number but got OrderedDict([('title', 'erwre'),
>   ('rate_per_kg', 53.0), ('discount', 5.0)]).

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_image_list')
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields='__all__'

    def get_image_list(self,obj):
        image_list=[]
        item_images = ItemImage.objects.filter(item=obj)
        request = self.context.get('request')
        for each in item_images:
            image_list.append(request.build_absolute_uri(each.image.url))
        return image_list
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_image_list')
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields='__all__'

    def get_image_list(self,obj):
```

The argument passed to the `obj` parameter is not an actual `Item object`, it's a dictionary that is passed to the serializer in the view. i.e `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)`.
This would work well if you were doing an update, then you could pass the `Item object` i.e `serializer = self.get_serializer(item, data=request.data)`

```
image_list=[]
item_images = ItemImage.objects.filter(item=obj)
request = self.context.get('request')
for each in item_images:
    image_list.append(request.build_absolute_uri(each.image.url))
return image_list
```

The `obj` arguement passed to the `get_<field>` method should be a model object,  Otherwise the call to `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will fail resulting to that error.